# Chrome Webstore Extension Download interrupts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a light weight chrome extension . Of the late downloading the extension from webstore is giving Error with " Download Interrupted " alert and failed server problem in download file.

[image]

On checking the chrome://net-internals/#events , I found the following log  . I am unable to decipher what it means . perhaps can help somebody else explain me what is going wrong here .

[image]

I am using Chrome  beta Version 39.0.2171.42 beta (64-bit) and  stable Version 38.0.2125.111 (64-bit). Error occurs on both and also occurs for my extension users .

I understand that it is a problem  of cache and I am able to successfully load the extension after clearing cache and in incognito mode . However I am looking for a more stable and user understandable solution for my clients .

Comment: PS : I have already tried asking this question in forum but have not got any response  there https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/BpCUTee1ji0

Comment: Your logs are only partially visible. Could you export net-internals.json and share it here (e.g. via pastebin)? In the drop-down at the upper-left corner, choose "Export".

Answer (score 1):

Are you signed into multiple Google accounts? Have you published the extension only to testers?

If the answer to either of those questions is yes (though it doesn't sound likely, since you said it works in incognito mode), then what might be happening is the account that's signed in as primary isn't one that you've added as a tester. In this case (for me) download fails.

Comment: Yup this is what was the issue for me I did not add the host account as the tester for private extensions